# How can I examine RUNLEVEL from a bash script on Rasbpian?

Tags: shell-script, raspbian, runlevel

I'm writing a bash script that needs to examine the current runlevel, and do different things depending on it. For most Linux distros, it seems there should be a `RUNLEVEL` environment variable, and if so it would be easy.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Rasbpian does not seem to set a `RUNLEVEL` variable.

Can I somehow have the runlevel value exported as an environment variable, or is there another way to examine the current runlevel from a script? Is there any other way than parsing the output from the `runlevel` command?

Comment: What happens when you try to get the runlevel using `runlevel` command or `who -r` command?

Comment: `runlevel` returns `3 2`, and `who -r` returns `run-level 2  Jan  8 21:56                   last=3`

Comment: So, your current run level is 2 and previous run level is 3. Do you need to have the command just give 2 for you?

Comment: If this is a shell script you are running manually then that is why: RUNLEVEL is exported by the rc.init system to the scripts it runs, it is not generally available in a regular login shell.

Comment: @psusi Ah, good to know. The script I'm creating _will_ be run by rc.init eventually, I just couldn't understand why the variable was not available while testing the script from the shell. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f2` should give you the output of current runlevel.

If you need it in a variable to use it in your script, you could have it as,

```
runlevel_variable=$(runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f2)
echo "$runlevel_variable"
```

The above gives me the current runlevel of my machine.